# How to autosum a full column in excel without circular reference?

Tags: excel, sum, formula, circular-reference

[image]

I would like to have in the red circle cell (**C19**) the sum of all the C column. I've tried using C1 to C50 in the formula (`=SUM(C1:C50)`). I use C1:C50 and not C1:C18 because if I add some lines before the final sum I would like those to be included in the final sum.

So 2 questions:

1) How can sum all the C column without only C1 (which is a date) and without C19 (to not cause the circular reference, since that is the cell where just the previous values should be sum and presented?

2) If there's a formula for that, would it auto-update if I add more lines (let's say I add another line and the final sum changes to C20)? Then C19 should also be add to the sum.

PS: the image is showing the formula for the B column because I will use the same formula in all columns, I just asked about C because there I have a working sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How can sum all the C column without only C1 (which is a date) and
>   without C19 (to not cause the circular reference, since that is the
>   cell where just the previous values should be sum and presented?

```
=SUM(C2:C18,C20:C50)
```

> 2) If there's a formula for that, would it auto-update if I add more
>   lines (let's say I add another line and the final sum changes to C20)?
>   Then C19 should also be add to the sum

If you were to insert a row between rows 2 and 18  with the above formula Excel will automatically change it to 
`=SUM(C2:C19,C21:C51)`

Comment: Thank you. That solves it. But I had to use =SUM(C2:C19;C21:C51)  ; and not ,

Answer (score 4):

I like to do the following:

- In a field in the row that I want to skip(i.e. A1), enter text that uniquely describes the row as the header/skip row (i.e. 'header-skip')
- In the column that I want to sum (i.e. B:B) without a circular reference, enter a "SUMIF" formula using the header text as part of the IF to skip.  =SUMIF(A:A, "<>header-skip", B:B)

For example

```
[   ][      A      ][                 B                 ]
[ 1 ][ header-skip ][ =SUMIF(A:A, "<>header-skip", B:B) ]
[ 2 ][             ][                9.5                ]
[ 3 ][             ][                7.5                ]
[ 4 ][             ][               25.0                ]
```

Your Formula on line 1 should now correctly show "42" without any circular reference.  This is easier for me to remember and faster for me to put in a sheet than using offsets, indexes, and indirects, etc.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `=SUBTOTAL(9, range)` then the totals calculated don't go toward later subtotals. In other words, if you have a subtotal in C19 (or other cells in Column C), then your subtotal at the end (e.g. C50) will ignore subtotals in that range (`=SUBTOTAL(9,C2:C49)`). In this way, you don't have to worry about omitting certain cell references from the range you wish to sum.

Comment: Nice [SUBTOTAL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-HP005209288.aspx) is a lot more straight forward than SUMS on ranges.

Comment: It's not working, I've tried =SUBTOTAL(9,C2:C49) and it gives me the same circular error. I also must use =SUBTOTAL(9;C2:C49), is this "," and ";" confusion relates to I'm using excel 2003?

Comment: my excel simple doesn't accept "," between function number and range. it asks for ";". What's wrong?

Comment: The ","/";" problem is probably due to your regional settings. If you are putting the `SUBTOTAL` formula within `C2:C49`, then yes it will be circular. If you wanted to sum up `C2:C49`, then you'd put a `SUBTOTAL` in `C50`. If you wanted to sum up `C2:C18`, then you'd put `=SUBTOTAL(9; C2:C18)` in `C19`. The key difference between `SUBTOTAL` and `SUM` is that your `SUBTOTAL` in `C19` wouldn't be added to the `SUBTOTAL` in `C50`. Make sense?

Comment: Yes makes sense. But would the subtotal auto-update if I put it in C19 and later insert a line before it (so it would become C20)? would it sum all that is before?

Comment: Yes, like many other formulas, if you insert rows/columns, then the range will be adjusted unless absolute references (e.g. `$A$2:$A$18`) are used.

Comment: Both solutions, yours and Conrad's work, the result is very similar to me. I believe SUBTOTAL may work better because if in the future I have to sum something else it will not oversum.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you're still interested but:
There is a work-around that will work and not give you a circular reference.

Here's an example from my own spreadsheet:  "=SUM(M1:OFFSET(M13,-1,0,1,1))"

Normally you'd sum a set of data with "=SUM(M1:M19)".

But if you want to do that AND still be able to add rows you need to incorporate an OFFSET formula.  OFFSET locates your reference cell and then moves up or down the number of cells you tell it to.

For example mine (above) finds M13 then moves UP one cell (-1) and the result is 1 cell tall by one cell wide (the 1,1).